# Automatically download iTunes Season Pass episodes?

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

I have three active iTunes Season Passes for various shows, the first ones I've gotten in years. However, it seems that apparently the episodes don't auto-download anymore? Is that right? And you can't even hit "check for available downloads"? Because that was a big part of the appeal for me, back when I had them for LOST and such: having new episodes automatically added to my library, so I could pull them up on the AppleTV or whatever without having to seek them out.

Currently, the only two ways I know of to get new episodes are to follow the link in the emails each week, or to manually go to the each show's page on iTunes and download the new episode each week.

Is that right? Is there any way, official or third-party, to automatically download (or at least batch-download) the new episodes from an iTunes Season Pass?

Comment: For what it's worth to anyone with the same issue, a batch-download solution can at least be found by going to the Purchases section of the iTunes Store, and selecting "Not In My Library." Then, at least, all your episodes are lined up and can be downloaded together, rather than having to go to each show page individually.